# The application requires that assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms Version 11.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) First

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce WPF application. It was installing correctly until I changed ReportViewer from Version 10 to Version 11.

I know get the following error when trying to install:

> The application requires that assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms Version 11.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) First.

How do I fix this and still have it using ClickOnce, I can't do a manual install as the users don't have permissions; they only have permissions to use ClickOnce.

I tried changing the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll Publish status from *Prerequisite* to *Include*, but still the error persists.

[image]

Comment: If you can't ask your users to get their machine updated then you are pretty stuck.

Comment: In your screenshot Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll is also set to Prerequisite. Set if to Include as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this to work on a machine with the same problem although I needed to download two .msi applications.

First I downloaded and installed SQLSysClrTypes. It is located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35580) as it is needed to install report viewer.

Just click download, it'll take you onto a page with a scroll bar. SQLSysClrTypes is near the bottom. Just tick that and hit next, and you can download and install that.

I got report viewer from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/B/7/FB728406-A1EE-4AB5-9C56-74EB8BDDF2FF/1033/x86/ReportViewer.msi).

After installing the both of them. I was able to grab from my ClickOnce with reportviewer 11 and it downloaded and ran successfully where previously I was having the exact same problem.

As an addendum, I was logged onto admin so this solution may not be the best if you don't have admin.

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a prerequisite to the installer.

1. Right click your project and go to *Properties*.
2. Click the *Publish* tab.
3. Click *Prerequisites...*.
4. Find *Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer* and check it. (There may be a different version available since the update, check for that.)

Upon installation of your application it will now download report viewer for the user.

Comment: will this mean the end user will need admin rights to install that? We are trying to include everything click once?

Comment: My best guess would be.. If they have access to install the click once, they will have access to install this component.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) package manager, you can install the Microsoft.Winforms.ReportViewer 11 version from there. This will get all the dependent DLL files, and everything will be there.